# Swap values between two rows of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following T-SQL code segment works but i'm wondering if there's a cleverer and/or less verbose way to accomplish the swapping of field values between two different rows. (The code has hard-coded pkey values for simplicity.)

```
BEGIN TRAN;

declare @swapFormSeqA int;
declare @swapFormSeqB int;

SELECT @swapFormSeqA = DisplaySeq
FROM CustomCatalogForm
WHERE CustomCatalogFormId = 1;

SELECT @swapFormSeqB = DisplaySeq
FROM CustomCatalogForm
WHERE CustomCatalogFormId = 2;

UPDATE CustomCatalogForm
SET DisplaySeq = @swapFormSeqB
WHERE CustomCatalogFormId = 1;

UPDATE CustomCatalogForm
SET DisplaySeq = @swapFormSeqA
WHERE CustomCatalogFormId = 2;

COMMIT TRAN;
```

EDIT: i'm using Sql2k5 specifically so 2k8 is not an option.

Comment: SQL 2000, 2005 or 2008? There are some interesting tricks in 2k8 around MERGE and OUTPUT, see http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
begin tran

declare @sum int

select @sum = sum(DisplaySeq)
from CustomCatalogForm
where CustomCatalogFormId in (1,2)

update CustomCatalogForm
set DisplaySeq = @sum - DisplaySeq
where CustomCatalogFormId in (1,2)

commit tran
```

Comment: Clever trick; works as long as the DisplaySeq values added won't overflow the limits of the type.

Comment: Very interesting trick Guffa but i don't see that it is deterministic? E.g. how are you guaranteed that the values will actually swap in the Update call? Is there some stacking logic you're depending on?

Comment: @psasik: It's rather simple, actually. First you get (x+y), then you can use that to calculate one value from the other: x = (x+y)-y and y = (x+y)-x.

Comment: Thanks Guffa, now i see it! It's so simple that i missed the first time around!

Comment: This does solve the problem and is definitely elegant, but it wouldn't work with non-numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
UPDATE CustomCatalogForm
SET DisplaySeq = (SELECT DisplaySeq
    FROM CustomCatalogForm T2
    WHERE T2.CustomCatalogFormId =
        -1*(CustomCatalogForm.CustomCatalogFormId -2) +1
    )
WHERE CustomCatalogFormId IN (1,2);
```

(warning: please test this first, as I cannot test it from here).

Comment: Yup, hnxs.  Should have been T2 both places.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks like this:

```
--drop table CustomCatalogForm
create table CustomCatalogForm
 (
    CustomCatalogFormId  int  not null
   ,DisplaySeq char(1) not null
 )

insert CustomCatalogForm (CustomCatalogFormId, DisplaySeq)
 values (1,'A')
insert CustomCatalogForm (CustomCatalogFormId, DisplaySeq)
 values (2,'B')
insert CustomCatalogForm (CustomCatalogFormId, DisplaySeq)
 values (3,'C')
insert CustomCatalogForm (CustomCatalogFormId, DisplaySeq)
 values (4,'D')
```

Then this will do it for any two given values (I tested with 2 and 3):

```
select * from CustomCatalogForm
-------------------------------
DECLARE
  @Item1 int
 ,@Item2 int

SET @Item1 = 2
SET @Item2 = 3

UPDATE CustomCatalogForm
 set DisplaySeq = ccf2.DisplaySeq
 from CustomCatalogForm ccf
  inner join (select CustomCatalogFormId, DisplaySeq
               from CustomCatalogForm
               where CustomCatalogFormId = @Item1
                or CustomCatalogFormId = @Item2) ccf2
   on ccf.CustomCatalogFormId <> ccf2.CustomCatalogFormId
 where ccf.CustomCatalogFormId = @Item1
  or ccf.CustomCatalogFormId = @Item2
-------------------------------
select * from CustomCatalogForm
```

The trick is to get both rows only on either side of the join, and join on NOT EQUALS.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
UPDATE ccf SET 
  DisplaySeq = Case CustomCatalogFormId 
     When 1 Then T2.DisplaySeq 
     When 2 Then T1.DisplaySeq  End
From CustomCatalogForm ccf 
    Join CustomCatalogForm T1 On T1.CustomCatalogFormId  = 1
    Join CustomCatalogForm T2 On T2.CustomCatalogFormId  = 2
Where ccf.CustomCatalogFormId  In (1,2)
```