# Copy content from one field to another

Tags: sql

I’m looking for a `SQL` query script:

```
COPY ContactName, City 
    WHERE CustomerID (A)
TO ContactName, City 
   WHERE CustomerID (B)
```

[image: EXAMPLE]

I know this isn’t right, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Regards!

Comment: I don't get it, do you want to update B ContactName with A's ContactName by using their unique ID`s?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131138/1822)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1331191/330315)

Comment: SQL tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Customers
SET ContactName = (SELECT ContactName WHERE CustomerID ='A'), City = (SELECT City WHERE CustomerID ='A')
WHERE CustomerID=B
```

This should work